# Unfamiliar Json length limit, REST WCF Service

Tags: wcf, json, .net-4.0

I feel need to ask for help in this case.

> [EDIT] Because the nature of GET and the focus of question (not "solve
>   it with POST). A reply which refer to reasons about the limit of
>   sending parameters to WCF, would be enough as an accepted answer.
>   [/EDIT]

I have a REST WCF Service method which uses json for communication.
The service and the client are on same domain. This system have a few of json services and methods which get and save data, which works just as they should. That will sa, no need to spend time on general setup proposals.

> The problem lie in this specific method, that have to send back a
>   rather big string of data to the service. Big in this context seem to be around >1500 characters.

The case it's an editor that load it's content from a simple request uri;

(GET) **WebService/Content.svc/GetContent(id)**

The user press SAVE-button and javascript are escaping the content and send to the service.
(GET) **WebService/Content.svc/SaveContent(id, escapedHtml)**

> (I know, there could be PUSH or POST)

The Webservice doing this very fine with a small amount of characters. I found the limit to be around 1500 characters. I can't find any reason to this. I tried different attributes as **maxRecievedMessageSize** and a lot of things that posts and blogs talking about same topic has ben solved with. This case looks have another kind of problem.

At the client, those config info are used (remember, the max size attributes does not make sense, I just take them into this sample to declare that),

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="204822000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="204822000" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  <service name="Namespace.Content">
    <endpoint address="" 
       behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehaviorConfig"
       binding="webHttpBinding" 
       bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfig"
       contract="Namespace.IContent" />
  </service>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment 
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

Content less then about 1500 bytes, Fiddler perfectly say:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5  
>    Webclient: Infometric - System Infomatrix X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>    Set-Cookie: HttpReferrer=localhost; path=/ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date:
>    Fri, 13 Jan 2012 14:27:37 GMT Content-Length: 0

When more then around 1500 bytes, Fiddler less nice say:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> Cache-Control: private
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
> jsonerror: true
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 14:29:32 GMT
>
> 69
> {"Message":"Authentication failed.",
>  "StackTrace":null,
>  "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException" }
> 0
> ```

The specific Question: How do I fix the (appear to be) max length limit make the editor possible to send it's whole content?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a post. I believe that the reason the get has a size transfer limit is to help minimize spamming to the web server. I also believe that if you want to change the max length limit that a get has, it has to be done on the web server it self. I dont think that a post has a max length limit (but i could be wrong(but its also worth try, right?))

Comment: I would then be happy for links or fact that leads to understanding of what the limitation are, why and if they can be avoided. Also to which cost (as you say, POST or PUT worth a try?).